# llenar variables con middleware express js

Tags: nodejs, express, jade

Estoy intentando llenar una variable con un middleware que recibe información a través de un request json y lo estoy almacenando en una variable global la que a posterior utilizo en un render con pug, pero los primeras cargas me devuelve errores una variable vacía, como puedo asegurar que se cargue previo a la visualización. 
aqui esta mi código

```
function fillVars(req, res, next){
     var urlCandidates = "https://web.com/count_by?group=true";
    request({url: urlCandidates,json: true }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        jsonTwiteros = body;
        }
    });
    next();
}
// function to call render
function render(req, res, next){
    console.log("Ingreso a render");
    res.render('main',{total:jsonTwiteros } );
        next();
}
function  close(req, res, next){
    res.end();
}
//set route 
app.get('/',fillVars, render,close);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas un middleware el next() significa que el request puede seguir viajando. Básicamente tu error esta en que el next debería estar dentro del callback del request, ya que sino no estas esperando a que este termine para decirle, continua con tu camino.

Te recomendaria que la variable se la agregues al response, acordate que el next() continua con el mismo response. Express tiene una variable dentro del response especialmente para realizar estas cosas.

Esta varialbe se llama: locals. Esta se encuentra dentro del response. Deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
function fillVars(req, res, next){
    var urlCandidates = "https://web.com/count_by?group=true";

    //Ejecuto el request
    request({
        url: urlCandidates,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        //Guardo el body
        res.locals.jsonTwiteros = (!error && response.statusCode === 200) ? body : {};

        //Una vez que terino el request y guarde la respuesta continuo con el request
        next();
    });
}
// function to call render
function render(req, res, next){
    res.render('main',{
        total: res.locals.jsonTwiteros
    } );

    next();
}

function close(req, res, next){
    res.end();
}

app.get('/',fillVars, render,close);
```